# Printing a NumericUpDown value out of a ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++, io, ofstream

This should be a simple task, but I am recieving a file containing the number "1" instead of the contents of the numericUpDown control. Using breakpoints I can see the value from
ta[i]->Value is the value I would expect it to be, but then after the conversion I get a 1 in the file instead of the value.

```
     private: void storePreviousSettings()
{
    ofstream settings("prev_settings.txt");
    if(settings.is_open())
    {
        settings << "#ta" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            settings << ta[i]->Value.ToString() << endl;
        }
        settings << "End" << endl;
        settings.close();
    }
}
```

Note: ta is defined like so:

```
private: NumericUpDown * ta[];
```

#### Why am I printing a "1" to the file with the ofstream instead of the value in the numericUpDown component? How can I fix this? Is there an alternative method for writing to a file can I perform?

#### Update/Current Failed Attempts

If I add this line:

```
System::String * temp = ta[i]->Value.ToString();
```

Before the "settings << ta[i]->Value ..."  line, using break points I can see that "temp" holds the expected value, and ta[i]->Value.ToString() is working. So when ta[i]->Value.ToString() is used with the << operator something must be changing in order for me to recieve a "1" in the file instead of the value I am seeing at my break points before it is wrote to the file.

Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved using the following conversion on the Decimal to make it a double.

```
    private: void storePreviousSettings()
{
    ofstream settings("prev_settings.txt");
    if(settings.is_open())
    {
        settings << "#ta" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            settings << System::Decimal::ToDouble(ta[i]->Value) << endl;
        }
        settings << "End" << endl;
        settings.close();
    }
}
```

If anyone knows the reason why using .ToString() did not work originally, please post. I am answering this in hopes that it might aid someone else in the same situation.